# Preserving sign on absolute minimum check

Tags: optimization, absolute-value, maxima-minima

I have a set $S=\{-3,-1,2,5\}$ and I know with $\mbox{abs}(S)$ I could get minimun distance from $0$. But problem is that I need to preserve sign. So I need to know that exactly $-1$ is the minimum value.

By computing this can be done by getting the index of minimum value and retrieving value from $S$ baded on that index.

Is there a math notation for this procedure. And the most important, is the other algebraic method for my problem?

Comment: Are you programming a computer to run this procedure?

Comment: No, but Id like to find an effective way to get the value in question by any computer language by not involving index usage. If ever possible.

Comment: Ok. I think I found it as simple as: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function

Comment: What about the set $\{ s \in S : |s| \leq |t| \forall t \in S \}$?

Comment: The last one seems to perfectly answer the question. At least in Python it is possible to do it so without using indeces. But probably indices are used internally anyway...